# Crodova: content source external and Plugins

Tags: php, html, cordova, admob, phonegap

i start a cordova project an edit the config.xml to an extern source. Like this:

```
<content src="MYURL_EXTERN" />
```

I tested with *cordova-plugin-admob-free* plugin.
Now the plugins no working only if i have the content source local. I think the conflict are the missing sources. And i think all plugins will not work. I hope you understand my problem with my bad english ;)

Regard

Comment: Can you please explain more ? 
do you want to upload code admob from your server or what ?

Comment: No i only want to say cordova run directly from my extern server. But all my plugins no working. If i changed:

<content src="MYURL_EXTERN" />

to 

<content src="index.html" />

all is fine.